# output of if-else command not being redirected

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

When I run the command:

```
if exist file.txt (echo yes) else (echo no) > "output.txt" 2>&1
```

in a command prompt, if 'file.txt' doesn't exist, a file 'output.txt' is created reading 'no', whereas if 'file.txt' does exist, 'yes' is output to the console window and the file 'output.txt' isn't even created.
I also executed a batch file:

```
if exist file.txt (echo yes) else (echo no) > "output.txt" 2>&1
pause
```

and the result was the same, when 'file.txt' does exist 'yes' only appears in the console window.
What's the reason, and how do I get all the output to redirect to 'output.txt' consistently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(if exist file.txt (echo yes) else (echo no) )> "output.txt" 2>&1
```

I think the problem is only a matter of parenthesis

Comment: …which can be reduced to `(If Exist "file.txt" (Echo yes) Else Echo no) 1>"output.txt"`, because there should be no stdout, and the `Else` command does not need to be parenthesized.